# How is an api call made to an endpoint?

Tags: javascript, php, json, laravel, flutterwave

I am trying to integrate an escrow payment system in a project i am working on but kind of confused about how this goes.Newbie

I have already set up the inline payment in my page along other requirements similar to stripe.

Now it has to do with settling an escrow payment and to do that When the funds are in escrow and I would like to settle the seller for the funds i would need to call the settlement endpoint. `https://ravesandboxapi.flutterwave.com/v2/gpx/transactions/escrow/settle`
This is a sample request

```
{
    "id": "348813", // this is the txid value returned in the v2/verify response.
    "secret_key": "FLWSECK-*************************-X" // your merchant secret key.
}
```

and this is a sample response

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "message": "SUCCESS",
    "data": "Transaction settled"
}
```

How exactly is the api call made using the above.

Comment: You need to go back to that api provider's website. There should be sample code on how to make a remote call. But my first instinct in regards to PHP is via `CURL`.. But they would tell you the variables to pass etc

Comment: Your life would be made easier using one of their SDKs. If you're using Laravel, there's a Laravel-specific library listed here: https://developer.flutterwave.com/docs/plugins#section-php-sdk

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Guzzle. It's a pretty simple PHP package to handle API routing.

http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client(['base_uri' => 'https://ravesandboxapi.flutterwave.com']);

$response = $client->request('GET', 
  '/v2/gpx/transactions/escrow/settle',
  ['json' => ['id' => '348813', 'secret_key' => 'KEY']
);

$body = $response->getBody();
$responseData = $body->getContents();
```

Answer (score 0):

When using PHP I always use a function like this one I'm sharing which I find quite useful. I think it's quite self explanatory but in case you need further assistance please let me know.

```
function CallAPI($method, $url, $data, $id, $secret_key) {

    $headers = [
        "Content-type: application/json",
        "id: ".$id,
        "secret_key: " .$secret_key
    ];

    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    switch ($method) {
        case "GET":
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
            break;
        case "POST":
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
            break;
        case "PUT":
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
            break;
        case "DELETE":
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "DELETE");
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
            break;
    }

    curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_HEADER         => false,    //return headers in addition to content
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,     // follow redirects
        CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,     // set referer on redirect
        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 30,       // timeout on connect
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 30,       // timeout on response
        CURLOPT_NOBODY        =>  0,        // timeout on response
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 9,        // stop after 10 redirects
        CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT    => true,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => true,     // Disabled SSL Cert checks
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION   => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER      => $headers
    ));

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
            return json_decode($result, true);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

just use guzzle library. i made a simple boilerplate just for API call i used in any project

https://gist.github.com/afiqiqmal/777fc6383ffce11113dc379094ee18b4

Sample use

```
$result = (new ApiRequest())
     ->baseUrl("https://ravesandboxapi.flutterwave.com")
     ->setHeader([
        'id' => $id,
        'secret_key' => $secretKey
     ])
     ->requestUrl("v2/gpx/transactions/escrow/settle")
     ->fetch();
```